# OLD Chamberlain Liftmaster (1280R) garage door won't close but both the green and orange lights are steadily lit

Tags: garage-door-opener

I can only close the door by holding down the wall button the whole time and the remotes won't work at all. The motor LED blinks 4 times and the overhead light blinks 10 times - so both are indicating the sensors aren't lined up. **But both the green and the orange sensor lights are STEADY**.

Do I just randomly start moving them around? It makes no sense. I've tried unplugging the unit as a way to "reset" but that did nothing. I know it's old but I'd rather not replace. And yeah, I've cleaned off the sensors 3 times (it worked in the past but not this time around).

Comment: *"it's old but I'd rather not replace"* Sometimes you have to do things you'd rather not do. Or you'll waste **more** time and money trying to fix things that are past their lifespan than it would cost to replace them.

Comment: I'd guess that the sensors are knocked out of alignment. Someone probably bumped them or something. I don't recall the light colors, etc. but when my garage door sensors get knocked out of alignment the button needs to be held to get it to close. Visually inspect the sensors and see about re-aligning them. My guess is that one of them should not be lit... maybe the orange one figuring "green means go"?

Comment: My opener was doing the same flashing but green and amber lights were both lit, seemingly indicating the sensors were in alignment.  Readjusting the sensors did the trick and got the door to close properly without all the flashing.